# C# serial port, simulation of serialport write

Tags: c#, serial-port, emulation, simulation, com0com

I have a c# app that connects pc to a device, through a serial port.

When I send data to the device, if the device sends data back, the datareceived event fires.

And I want to ask this.
Is there a way to simulate the data sending of the device?

I mean, i want to fire datareceived event not only when the device send data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have an additional free [serial port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port).

If need be, you may:

- just add another new one or
- install a virtual COM port solution (such as [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/)).

You can harness your C# program using a software [emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator) of the device through [Null modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I took a quick look at the com0com, but i dont think its what i want. What i want is if it is possible through my code to simulate the datareceiving from a device. For example I have one app and when i press a button, this app simulates the data sending from a serial port, in order to fire SerialPort.DataReceived  that exists in another app.

Comment: That's what emulator are for. It's supposed to emulate the device. In your usecase, communication is made through serial port and using com0com is just another way to emulate a serial port if you don't have another extra one. Otherwise, how could you fire a *serial* DataReceived event ?

Comment: Yes, you were right. I had it different in my mind. When i read it more carefully, i found the solution. 
Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you. As you are a fresh beginner on Stackoverflow, I remind you that you may accept the answer by clicking on the rigth button (whose icon is like a tickmark). Take time to visit all sections of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It helps you a lot to make plenty of progress.

Comment: I'll take a look at FAQ's. 
Let me ask you one more question. I'ce created a pair of virtual COMs, to use to my app. When i created them, i can use them without problem.
But when i restart my pc, the app gives me an error that COM port doesnot exits. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: I did not have trouble at all trying Com0Com 6 months ago: It is a kernel-mode virtual serial port driver for Windows. Installing must be made carefully. You must observe a strict adherence to what is said in the ReadMe.txt (see Install & FAQs & HOWTOs sections). Uninstall it and try again.